# Extending bootstrap using the Grails bootstrap plugin not working as expected

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the Grails bootstrap plugin found [here](https://github.com/groovydev/twitter-bootstrap-grails-plugin). Just in case it matters I am mainly using the asset pipeline but I do still include the resource pipeline for backwards compatibility.

I then create (per the instructions) another file called custom-bootstrap.less

```
@import "bootstrap.less";
```

and then another file called events.less

```
/*
 *= require custom-bootstrap
 */
@import "bootstrap.less";
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color:#d3d3d3;
}
```

This fails with no formatting. I tried something else by changing the event.less to...

```
/*
*= require bootstrap
*/
@import "bootstrap.less";
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color:#d3d3d3;
}
```

Now I see the bootstrap styling but the less file fails to compile and throws a grails error.

> No signature of method: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined.replaceAll()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String,
>   asset.pipeline.processors.CssProcessor$_process_closure1) values:
>   [url([\'\"]?([a-zA-Z0-9-_./\@#\?\ \&+\%\=]+)[\'\"]?), ...]

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to convert to plugin version 3.1.1.3

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this error when asset pipeline was unable to resolve the path to the imported file.
See http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#organization for details.